# `tellp` and `tellg` when file is opened in and out

Tags: c++, c++11

With

```
fstream file("test.txt",ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

are `tellp` and `tellg` the same for `file`? Or `seekp` and `seekg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `std::filebuf`, the buffer used by `std::fstream`, has only one pointer. `seekg` and `seekp` move the same pointer, and `tellg` and `tellp` return its position.

(an example of a stream where the pointers are different is `std::stringstream`)

The standard specifies this in `§27.9.1.1[filebuf]/3`

> A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence